# Cordova 5 not handling new ios application target in XCode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, cordova-5.0.0

I just upgraded to Cordova 5. Any XCode project that has more than one application target causes an error on build.

```
cordova build ios
could not find -Info.plist file, or config.xml file.
```

Steps to recreate:

1. Create a new Cordova project
2. Add iOS as a platform
3. In the XCode project, duplicate the application target to create a new target
4. Run "cordova build ios"

Currently using XCode 6.3.2 and Cordova 5.1.1

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue ? I've got the same error.

Comment: I just answered a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245416/cordova-doesnt-work-with-ios-multiple-targets/33081328#33081328 Hope this helps :)

Comment: look at here: [The second comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33081328/3392609)

Answer (score 0):

There is a pull request with a fix: https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/pull/219

Until Cordova team fix it, look here:

[Second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33081328/3392609)